# Ignore / remove log patterns in Apache's access_log

Tags: apache, logging

I have a working Apache with mod_cluster with a minimal configuration:

(mod_jk.conf)

```
LoadModule cluster_slotmem_module modules/mod_cluster_slotmem.so
LoadModule manager_module modules/mod_manager.so
LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so
LoadModule advertise_module modules/mod_advertise.so    

Listen 5555    
<VirtualHost *:5555>

  LogLevel warn
  <Directory />
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Location />
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Location>

  ManagerBalancerName mybalancer
  ServerAdvertise on
  EnableMCPMReceive On

  <Location /mod_cluster-manager>
    SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is, in my access_log I have:

```
...
ClusterListener/1.0
ClusterListener/1.0
ClusterListener/1.0
ClusterListener/1.0
ClusterListener/1.0
ClusterListener/1.0
ClusterListener/1.0
ClusterListener/1.0
ClusterListener/1.0
ClusterListener/1.0
ClusterListener/1.0
ClusterListener/1.0
...
```

I don't want to log these 'ClusterListener/1.0' in my access_log.

I've tried to change my LogLevel in httpd.conf:

```
...
LogLevel warn
...
```

And I've tried to put 'LogLevel' in my mod_jk.conf

However, these options didn't work. What do I need to do to remove these logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. I undo the '**LogLevel** **warn**' to the original configuration , because this doesn't solve the problem. Sharing with all.

All I had to do is to add this to my httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule log_config_module>
    #....

    SetEnvIf User-Agent "ClusterListener/1\.0" dontlog

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" env=!dontlog

     #...
</IfModule>
```

And now, my access_log doesn't have more the "ClusterListener" logs.